# Como puedo pasar el valor de dos variables obtenidas por un Select (datatable) y enviarlas a otra página?

Tags: javascript, mvc, datatables

buen dia... me podrian ayudar con lo siguiente: En una pagina llamada "Recursos.cshtml" tengo un datatable(#tabla) de esa tabla hice un select cell utilizando el siguiente código:

```
  //--Seleccionar Producto--//
    $('#tabla tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var categoria = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
        var numero = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
        console.log(categoria);
        console.log(numero);

        //Redirigir a otra pagina
        var url = '@Url.Action("IngresosDetalle", "Operaciones")';
        window.location.href = url;
```

De esa manera obtendo el valor de la primera y segunda columna. Al momento de dar click sobre la celda me redirige a otra pagina y en esa pagina tengo un formulario con dos inputs que ahi es donde quiero que se coloquen los dos datos que obtuve de las dos columnas.De antemano agradeceria su ayuda. Si tengo algo mal redactado perdonen, soy novato en esto.

```
<div class="card-body p-1 row g-1">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <!--Primer Campo-->
                            <select id="fcbocategoria" class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example" style="height: 32px; font-size: 12px">
                                <option value="0" disabled>TIPO INGRESO</option>;
                                <option value="LOCAL">LOCAL</option>
                                <option value="IMPORTACION">IMPORTACION</option>
                                <option value="EXCEDENTE">EXCEDENTE</option>
                                <option value="PRODUCCION">PRODUCCION</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <!--2do Campo-->
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <input type="text" id="txtNumero" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="0" disabled="disabled" style="height: 32px; font-size: 14px">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <input type="date" id="txtfechainicio" class="form-control" placeholder="" onload="getDate()" min="2000-10-10" max="2030-12-31" style="height: 32px; font-size: 14px" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <input type="text" id="txtEstatus" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="" disabled="disabled" style="font-size: 12px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

> Estos dos campos son de la pagina en donde la cual quiero pintar los dos datos que traigo como lo muestro en la parte de arriba var Categoria y var numero esas dos variables las quiero pintar en estos dos campos

Comment: Pon el html de esos inputs tambien en la pregunta. Pulsa sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la pregunta para editarla y agregar la información que haga falta.

Comment: @masterguru ya hermano, pagina1.html = de la tabla de esa pagina extraje Var categoria y var Numero al seleccionar una celda de la tabla. Pagina2.html son los campos en cual quiero pintar los datos que traigo,

Comment: Categoria: Select y Numero: input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no quieres pasarles parámetros a la URL yo lo haria usando [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) de este modo:

```
$('#tabla tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var categoria = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
        var numero = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
        console.log(categoria);
        console.log(numero);

        localStorage.setItem('categoria',categoria);
        localStorage.setItem('numero',numero);

        //Redirigir a otra pagina
        var url = '@Url.Action("IngresosDetalle", "Operaciones")';
        window.location.href = url;
```

y en la otra página lo colocaria así;

```
fcbocategoria.value = localStorage.getItem('categoria');
txtNumero.value = localStorage.getItem('numero');
localStorage.removeItem('categoria');
localStorage.removeItem('numero');
```

### Explicación

Usamos **localStorage** para almacenar temporalmente valores que van a compartirse en el mismo dominio, en este caso la *categoría* y el *número*, de este modo:

```
localStorage.setItem('categoria',categoria);
localStorage.setItem('numero',numero);
```

para luego, al abrir la nueva página, recuperarlos mediante [getItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem), asignándolos a los *inputs/select* correspondientes, y luego los borramos con [removeItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeitem) para que no quede nada de eso en localStorage.

Piensa que eso solo funcionará siempre y cuando **numero** y **categoria** tengan valores asignados y guardados correctamente en *localStorage*. En caso contrario es probable que de un error de javascript porque no estamos comprobando el *getItem()* de esas claves pues asumimos que siempre tendran valor. Si no lo quieres así debes filtrarlo adecuadamente.

Ya nos diras si te ha funcionado o lo querias de otra forma.

Comment: me funciono perfectamente, me interesa aprender y gracias a tu ayuda pude comprender mejor. Te lo agradezco bastante que amable. Te queria hacer otra consulta, actualmente tengo un proyecto y en ello estoy esforzandome y gracias a Dios ahi voy pero en cosas asi como estas para mi son complicadas porque soy novato, podria explicarte la otra duda? para los que saben es algo sencillo para mi es complicadisimo, la duda que tengo no es que me hagas todo, unicamente que reemplace una celda ya registrada y que la actualice sumandolo con el nuevo dato.

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido.  Si esta respuesta satisface tu pregunta deberías marcarla como **Aceptada** para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede pendiente eternamente. En este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo. En cuanto a tu otra pregunta dentro de tu comentario, no te puedo responder porque me falta un [example] válido para hacerlo, en definitiva, una nueva pregunta bien explicada con todos los datos necesarios para reproducir tu problema. Así es como funciona este sitio, pues no es un foro,lo siento

Comment: perdone ya hice la pregunta hace unos dias antes pero usted fue el que me respondio pero no me habia dado cuenta, ya actualice mi problema en mi anterior pregunta.